# iterate through every xml node and append node and value to string

Tags: vb.net, xml-parsing

I have following xml Format,which is actually a kml file for google map..

```
        <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
          <Document>
            <Name>TestDoc</Name>
            <Style id="Style1">
              <PolyStyle>
                <fill>0</fill>
              </PolyStyle>
            </Style>
            <Folder>
              <Name>Folder1</Name>
              <Placemark>
                <Name>Placemark1Folder1</Name>
                <LookAt>
                  <longitude>-122.0839597145766</longitude>
                  <latitude>37.42222904525232</latitude>
                </LookAt>
              </Placemark>
              <Placemark>
                <Name>Placemark2Folder1</Name>
                <LookAt>
                  <longitude>-101.083959</longitude>
                  <latitude>26.422</latitude>
                </LookAt>
              </Placemark>
            </Folder>
            <Folder>
              <Name>Folder2</Name>
              <Placemark>
                <Name>Placemark1Folder2</Name>
                <LookAt>
                  <longitude>-96.566556</longitude>
                  <latitude>14.422</latitude>
                </LookAt>
              </Placemark>
            </Folder>
          </Document>
        </kml>
```

I want to concat xml to string variable untill it finds `<Folder>` node

Hence output string will be :

```
""<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"><Document><Name>TestDoc</Name><Style id="Style1"><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle> </Style>"
```

I am new to xml ..Plz help

Comment: what do you really want .. what happen with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646160/splitting-xml-document-according-to-node) ?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646160/splitting-xml-document-according-to-node) in this link...u have made input xml as string ..thats not my requirement ..i should treat input xml as xml format not a string ..so i have not tested your code and hence change my logic to accomplish this task..

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. "Iterate through each node until it finds node and append node with value"..what?

Comment: @James question is edited ..

Answer (score 3):

Ok i got it ...here is my solution

```
Public Sub ConcatXmlToString()
        Dim xmldoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
        '================================
        'Hard Coded
        '================================
        Dim ConcatString As String = "<?xml version=" & Chr(34) & "1.0" & Chr(34) & "encoding=" & Chr(34) & "UTF-8" & Chr(34) & "?><kml xmlns=" & Chr(34) & "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" & Chr(34) & ">"

        xmldoc.Load("E:\A01c.kml")
        Dim DocumentNodeList As XmlNodeList = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Document")
        For Each DocumentNode As XmlNode In DocumentNodeList
            'xmldoc.ParentNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(childnode)
            Dim ChildNodeList As XmlNodeList = DocumentNode.ChildNodes
            For Each ChildNode As XmlNode In ChildNodeList
                If ChildNode.Name <> "Folder" Then
                    ConcatString = ConcatString & ChildNode.OuterXml.Replace("xmlns=""http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2""", "")
                End If
            Next
        Next

        ConcatString = ConcatString & "</Document></kml>"

        Dim str As String = xmldoc.InnerText

    End Sub
```

Comment: what is this all about ?? Found intresting but couldnt understand. Would you explain me abt all this??

Comment: @Binod its actually about splitting a google map of kml files according to placemark...